# 'undefined reference to 'function'

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have downloaded the library `libcomplearn` and want to test it in a small example program. But when I link it I get the error undefined reference to ‘function’.

I installed the library to a specific path.

OS: Debian

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "complearn.h"
#include "complearn/complearn-ncd.h"

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
    printf("Number from my library\n");

    CompLearnNcd *ncd = complearn_ncd_top();
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
FILES = test
LIBPATH = /try/libcomplearn/lib/pkgconfig
OUTPUT = TK_1
LIBNAME = complearn
#--------------------------------------------------

CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -c -Wall `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBPATH) && pkg-config --cflags $(LIBNAME)`
LDFLAGS = -static `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBPATH) && pkg-config --libs --static $(LIBNAME) -llzma`

all: Release

Debug: CFLAGS += -g
Debug: $(OUTPUT)

Release: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(OUTPUT).o
    @echo "started...."
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OUTPUT).o $(LDFLAGS)
    @echo "done...."

$(OUTPUT).o: $(FILES).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(FILES).c -o $(OUTPUT).o

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT).o $(OUTPUT)
```

**Output**

```
gcc -c -Wall `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/try/libcomplearn/lib/pkgconfig && 
pkg-config --cflags complearn` test.c -o TK_1.o
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:19: warning: unused variable ‘ncd’ [-Wunused-variable]
 CompLearnNcd *ncd = complearn_ncd_top();
               ^~~
started....
gcc -o TK_1 TK_1.o -static `export                 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/try/libcomplearn/lib/pkgconfig && pkg-config --libs --    
static complearn -llzma`
Unknown option -llzma
/usr/bin/ld: TK_1.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `complearn_ncd_top'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:28: TK_1] Error 1
```

I also tried with the command:

```
gcc test.c `-L/try/libcomplearn/lib/ -llzma` `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

Comment: When you add custom header file you must compile this to .o file and every .o file to executable or (bad way) include .c.

Comment: your LDFLAGS are not correct.

Comment: Blaze 
Yes, it’s in there, but it’s the same for all other functions.

IgorGalczak
There is nothing customized in the headers. I just corrected one include but before installing the library

Comment: @alinsoar Thanks for the hint. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I had similar problems in the past, just try to pass "-llzma" as the last option. I don't know why, but gcc (ld) complains if the libraries linking options are before the object file (or source file in your example).  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> I also tried with the command:

```
gcc test.c `-L/try/libcomplearn/lib/ -llzma` `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

which indicates that you do not understand [back-ticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands),
since:

```
`-L/try/libcomplearn/lib/ -llzma`
```

is not a meaningful use of them. Take the time now to learn their use.

The cause of your linkage failure is the setting:

```
LDFLAGS = -static `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBPATH) && pkg-config --libs --static $(LIBNAME) -llzma`
```

in the makefile.

Here you have `-llzma` within the back-tick expansion:

```
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBPATH) && \
    pkg-config --libs --static $(LIBNAME) -llzma`
```

To expand this, the shell executes:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBPATH)
pkg-config --libs --static $(LIBNAME) -llzma
```

`-llzma` is a meaningless option to the `pkg-config` command, so it fails,
as you see it complain in the `make` output:

```
Unknown option -llzma
```

Just like:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs zlib -llzma
Unknown option -llzma
```

As a result, the required linkage options that should be output by:

```
pkg-config --libs --static $(LIBNAME)
```

are not output and are not interpolated into the value of `LDFLAGS`. So the linkage
fails:

```
test.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `complearn_ncd_top'
```

because `libcomplearn` has not been linked. Correct the setting of your `LDFLAGS`
to:

```
LDFLAGS = -static `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBPATH) && pkg-config --libs --static $(LIBNAME)` -llzma
```

with `-llzma` following after the back-tick expansion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It solved a lot of problems and I got the point of  back-ticks. But I have now the error cannot find -llzma. Is then here maybe the linux version a problem?

Comment: @garafa Glad that helped and welcome to Stackoverflow! Here is [our way of saying "Thanks"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
There certainly is a linux `liblzma` but you probably just haven't installed the dev package: `sudo apt install liblzma-dev`. If you still have problems then
[ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). (One question at a time on SO).

Answer (score 0):

From [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

The order of the -l options is very important. Just pass -llzma as the last linking option.

Comment: Where do you exactly mean?
In the makefile under LDFLAGS?

Comment: For link options you use the LDFLAGS variable.